# Complex integral - double pole on the contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have this integral ($-1 \le a < 0$)
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{1+a\cos\theta}$$
which can be found as the real part of
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i n \theta}}{1+a\cos\theta}.$$

Now, I can solve it and find that it is equal to
$$2 \pi \frac{z_{+}^{n}}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}},$$

where $z_{+}$ is the smaller root of $a z^{2} + 2 z + a = 0$.

The thing I need to ask, though, is how do we treat the case of the degenerate root? In that case, we have a double pole, which lies on the contour (circle of radius $-1/a$). How do we solve the integral in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're integrating from $\theta=0$ to $2\pi$.
The quadratic $a z^2 + 2 z + a$ has a double root when $a = \pm 1$.  In those cases the integral diverges.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the limits. Doesn't the case of the double pole have to yield the same answer as when the poles are not degenerate, and only one of them is inside the contour?

Comment: What is "the same answer"?  The limit as $a \to 1$ or $a \to -1$ is infinite.